# Tikz plot with log y axis does not show 1-values

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

When I set the y axis to be logarithmic, the bars for the value range [0,1) are not rendered, as you can see here:

[image: Rendered plot]

Why is that? And how can I fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
1,3
2,2
3,1
4,1
5,0
6,1
6,2
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  ybar,
  ymode=log
]
\addplot [color=gray,fill] table [
    x index=0,
    y index=1,
    col sep=comma
] {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: $1=10^0$, so it seems to me that it works fine. Except that it should have thrown an error for $x=5$ because $\log(0)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: 10^0 is 1 but the axis starts at 0, so why does it not render from the bottom up to 10^0?

Comment: By the way I also tried explicitly setting ymin=0; same result

Comment: OK, I understand your question now. It'd have been clearer if there had been some values in the range you wanted. For some reason, I can't get this to work properly with table, but it works fine with coordinates instead. Do you need to get values from an external file?

Comment: Also, ymin=0 is undefined in log scale, you should use something like ymin=1e-2 instead (but, as I said above, it's not the cause of the problem anyway).

Comment: @Miyase Not necessarily. Can you guide me on what you mean by coordinates?

Comment: **The logarithm of a negative number (including zero) is undefined**, see https://www.rapidtables.com/math/algebra/ln/Ln_of_Negative_Number.html or any other Google result for "log negative numbers". This is unrelated to LaTeX or pgfplots :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking about the value range [0,1), but you do not have any values in this range. To include zero does not make sense on a logarithmic axis.

I have changed your values for testing and included `log origin=infty` assuming you want your bars to start from the bottom of the axis.

```
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
1,0.1
2,0.2
3,0.3
4,0.4
5,1
6,2
7,3
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
ymode=log,
log origin=infty,
]
\addplot[gray, fill] table[
x index=0,
y index=1,
col sep=comma
] {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Logarithmic y bar graph]

Without `log origin=infty`:

[image: Logarithmic y bar graph starting from 1]

Comment: +1: Never heard of `log origin=infty` :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `coordinates` and `ymin`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  ybar,
  ymode=log,
  ymin=1e-2
]
\addplot [color=gray,fill] coordinates {
    (1,3)
    (2,2)
    (3,1)
    (4,1)
    (5,0)
    (6,1)
    (7,0.1)    
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: bar]

Comment: There is no difference on using table or coordinates

Comment: @hpekristiansen In theory I agree, but on my system the graph never extends to negative y values with table, while it does with coordinates (as I said in a comment below the question). No idea why.

Comment: You do not mean negative y values, but negative exponents. You probably have not noticed that `filecontents` is not overwriting the `data.dat` file, so you are working with some old/original data.

Comment: Yes, negative log(y), sorry. As for the second part, no I cleaned everything before each compilation so there was no old data to work with.

Comment: So the code in my answer compiles differently on your computer!!?